# Open IntelliJ terminal window from windows batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, intellij-idea, terminal

I am using IntelliJ community edition and trying to find out how to start a terminal session using windows batch file.

For background - In our application, we need to run zookeeper, kafka and a spring-boot app before I can run my spring boot app.  Currently, I run each of them individually, in a command window.  I am working on a script but that opens 3 command windows.  I would like them to start a intellij terminal session when i run it from within intellij.

```
StartApps.bat

Start "Zookeper Server" cmd.exe /k "zkserver"
Start "Kafa" cmd.exe /k "H:\Software\kafka\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat H:\Software\kafka\config\server.properties"
Start "Initial Spring-boot" cmd.exe /k "java -jar H:\workspace\StarterApp.jar"
```

When I open a Terminal session in Intellij and run the above batch file, it opens 3 windows command windows for each of the calls.  I would like it to open a Intellij Terminal session, so that i don't have to keep on alternating between different windows when developing and testing my app, that need the above three to be running

Hopefully, there is a solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: ask the community or support of IntelliJ they might be able to help you although it is not an open-source IDE.

Comment: It's not possible right now. Request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. @ZOLDIK IntelliJ IDEA Community is open source: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community .

Comment: @CrazyCoder added request on the support site - IDEA-224248